# dart Format 0.052 to 0.06

Tags: dart, flutter

How dart implements java with help

```
BigDecimal b7= b6.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.01")).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
```

Format 0.052 to 0.06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the [decimal dart package](https://github.com/a14n/dart-decimal/):

```dart
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';
import 'dart:math';

Decimal setScale(Decimal decimal, int scale, Decimal roundMethod(Decimal decimal)) {
  Decimal scaleVal = Decimal.fromInt(pow(10, scale));
  return roundMethod(decimal * scaleVal) / scaleVal;
}

Decimal setScaleRoundDown(Decimal decimal, int scale) => setScale(decimal, scale, (val) => val.floor());
Decimal setScaleRoundUp(Decimal decimal, int scale) => setScale(decimal, scale, (val) => val.ceil());
Decimal setScaleRound(Decimal decimal, int scale) => setScale(decimal, scale, (val) => val.round());

void main() {
  print(setScaleRound(Decimal.parse('0.052'), 2));      // 0.05
  print(setScaleRoundUp(Decimal.parse('0.052'), 2));    // 0.06
  print(setScaleRoundDown(Decimal.parse('0.052'), 2));  // 0.05
}
```

Comment: @user5531997 you're welcome, would you mind accepting the answer if it solves your problem? thanks.